# How many permutations have the letters $N$ and $D$ separated by exactly two letters

Tags: probability, permutations

How many have the letters $N$ and $D$ separated by exactly two letters from the letters of the words $INCLUDE$

Comment: How many permutations of the letters in INCLUDE is my guess. In which case, (a) this is homework, and (b) this is trivial.

Comment: Edited title to reflect Comment and Answer. Related, slightly more complex problem. A group of $n$ friends (including one couple) are seated randomly, adjacently in a row. What is the distribution of $X$ the number of seats between the two people who are a couple. (Triangular.) This question asks for $P(X = 2)$ with $n = 7.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m assuming that you want to know how many permutations of the letters of the word $INCLUDE$ have the $N$ and $D$ separated by exactly two of the other letters.

HINT:

- How many permutations are there of the letters $I,C,L,U$, and $E$?
- Given a permutation of the letters $I,C,L,U$, and $E$, in how many different ways can you insert the letters $N$ and $D$ so that they are separated by exactly two of the other letters?
- How should the answers to the first two questions be combined to give the desired result?

Comment: Don't forget that N and D can be in either order: How do you get to 960?

Comment: @Bruce: I deliberately omitted the point about the order of $N$ and $D$, leaving it for the OP to realize. Accounting for it of course does produce $960$ as the final result.

Comment: My comment was intended for OP. I figured that with a gap of 5 hours after your helpful hint, maybe it was time for a little more encouragement. Even then, I didn't show all the steps. Never sure whether lack of response is lack of effort or of understanding.

Comment: @Bruce: Okay; I wasn’t entirely sure whether it was aimed at me, at the OP in general, or even at a comment by the OP that was deleted before I saw it.